# Using subprocess to send command to a new screen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am having a hard time constructing a workable python subprocess  that accomplishes what i usually do in command line. The examples that i found are not clear or don't involve opening screens.
This is what i do in terminal:
I open a new screen  to the usb device.

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

once the screen is up i can pass an AT command:
Like AT

```
AT
```

the generic reply(output) from that command is usually OK:

```
OK
```

Now i would like to do all this using sub-process to open new screen, pass command and get output using something similar to below code. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.call("screen -S /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 -X eval 'stuff \"AT\012\"'",   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will block until the child process terminates.  You'll probably need to create your own `Popen` object.

Comment: don't use `call` and `PIPE` together. Try PySerial